# How do you deserialize json with vendor specific content type in .Net?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

The json I get back from an API call is returned with the content type set to

application/vnd.company-v1+json

Unfortunately, the built in JsonMediaTypeFormatter does not understand this content type and results in error

No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read object of type

I have tried explicitly adding the special Media Type to SupportedMediaTypes collection of JsonMediaTypeFormatter. Results in the same error.

However, I am able to sub-class JsonMediaTypeFormatter, override its ReadFromStream method to deserialize the object

```
public class MyFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter{
    public MyFormatter():base(){
        SupportedMedaiTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.company-v1+json"));
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(...){
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try{
            var o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            taskSource.SetResult(o);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            taskSource.SetException(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

The above works. But I feel it's an overkill and I might be missing something simple.

Is this the right way or is there a better alternative?